# Dynamically inserting HTML DIV destroys jQuery DatePicker on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a single HTML page app, that contains a text input bound to a jQuery datepicker.  It is initialised/bound on startup, and it functions just fine.

The page has an inner container DIV, beneath the datepicker text input field, on the same page.

I am inlcuding an image, because I need to obscure some info:

[image]

When I dynamically insert a popup FORM into this inner container, it becomes visible, centered, floating over the container DIV.

```
<div id="CLC_Form">...</div>
var e = document.getElementById("contentDIV");
e.innerHTML += clc_div;
```

However, it also destroys the datepicker, clearing out the selected date, and making the datepicker field dead/unbound and unresponsive when I remove the added FORM (when the user clicks "Save" button on the popup FORM).

```
var e = document.getElementById("CLC_Form");
e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
```

Any ideas?  Please feel free to ask for additional info if I have not been thorough enough.

Thanks

Comment: innerHTML usually is a bad idea. Use createElement and appendChild instead.

Comment: Please include the relevant code as formatted text within the question, not as an image.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
e.innerHTML += clc_div;
```

I used:

```
e.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", clc_div);
```

Problem solved.